# How to turn Android phone into an USB gamepad for PC?

Tags: game-controllers

Is it possible to turn an Android phone into a USB gamepad for the PC? If yes, how?

Comment: USB gamepad for what? for a PC?

Comment: I tried out VirtualTablet and it worked pretty well. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sunnysidesoft.VirtualTablet.lite  but it is just wifi and not usb - but it gets you a keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 1):

There's a $43 USB device, [InputStick](http://inputstick.com/), that will do the trick. I bought this a few months ago for password entry from KeePass on Android, but the developer created the USB adapter so your android device can act as any conceivable USB device. Your android device connects to the USB dongle via bluetooth, and the desktop computer sees the USB dongle as any profile you choose.

The [gamepad](http://inputstick.com/index.php/usb-devices/gamepad) profile is built-in. From the description, it can emulate 4 axis and 16 buttons built-in, with the ability to customize as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Remote Gamepad](https://remotegamepad.com) allows you to use your phone as a game controller for your PC. I created this app because other apps are no longer available or do not work on newer phones.

You can use Remote Gamepad as the steering wheel in racing games by rotating your phone. On-screen controls are available similar to a game controller.

A PC with Windows 10 or later is required. This app is compatible with all PC games which support game controllers. Use a Wi-Fi or USB cable for the connection, no additional hardware is needed.

Remote Gamepad is available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.remotegamepad).